# Adding buttons into a java game

Tags: java, swing

How can I add a button to this code so it makes the text that say Play, Highscore and Exit into actual buttons, so when someone clicks it it does the thing they want it to do.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        //EkansBackground
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 600, 400);

        //EkansLogo
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int fontSize = 50;
        Font f = new Font("Marker felt", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
        g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString("---] EKANS [---", 180, 200);

        //Play button
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        int fontSize1 = 40;
        Font f1 = new Font("comic sans ms", Font.ITALIC, fontSize1);
        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("> PLAY <", 270, 280);

        //Play button
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("> EXIT <", 270, 380);

        //High Score button
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("> High Scores <", 215, 330);


    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `Frame` `Panel` `JButton` classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) class from Swing package.

```
JButton play = new JButton("> PLAY < ");
JButton exit = new JButton("> EXIT <");
JButton highscore = new JButton("> High Scores <");
this.add(play);
this.add(exit);
this.add(highscore);
```

Without any Layout's Manager, buttons will be placed according to a [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html), i.e. next to each other.

---

You can also use some JLabel to be used as a Button, it is more flexible to use if you have background image. With some MouseListener and Image as background, you can construct some great Button.

```
JLabel playLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./play.png"));

playLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
           playLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("./play_clicked.png");
           //Some action
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class constructor put:

```
JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
add(playButton);
```

If you want you can put it else where, but it is usually in the class constructor.

I suggest you learn about [swing components](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a own `Button`-class, if you want your game not to use the AWT or Swing components.
If you do it this way you won't have any problems with rendering other stuff in the background, using active rendering and you can completly define how a button acts.

But, as already mentioned, you can use AWT's `Button` or Swing's `JButton`.
If you do it this way you can simply add them to your `JPanel`.
But make sure you really draw them (If I remember right there is the method `paintComponents(Graphics)`).

You should also call `super.paintComponent();` at the beginning of your `paintComponent`-method.